# Outlook VSTO Add In - How to determine the item type when multiple windows are open

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an Outlook Add in developed which adds a string to the beginning of the subjects of emails, meeting request and so on.

The program detects the "CurrentItem" that is being displayed on the screen when the user first opens it.

For Example, The problem arises when the user begins a reply to an email, which tells the program that the current item is a reply. Then the user begins a new email before they send the reply, setting the current item to a mailItem. Then when they return to the reply that they began previously, the program still thinks that it is a mailItem, and therefore it breaks the application.

How can I fix this problem? Any help would be massively appreciated.

Here is the code that is hit when the user first creates a reply if it is helpful.

```
private void ThisAddIn_InlineResponse(object Item)
    {
        if (Item != null)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
        }
        TypeCheck = "inline";
    }
```

Essentially, I need to hit this code in the event that it is an inline reply, but I am seemingly unable to do this outside of the initialisation of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Application.ItemSend` event to process the items when they are actually sent. Use the `Class` property (you can access it dynamically, all OM objects expose it) to determine the item type (e.g. 43 for `OlObjectClass.olMail`).

Comment: Hi there, Thank you very much for the answer, could you possibly give me an example of how I could use this code to determine if it is a current Mail item or a meeting item?

Comment: If you don't want to dynamically retrieve the Class property, you can use the "as" operator the way you do it now and check if the resulting variable is null.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and implement this now. Appreciate the help a lot. Your application Outlook Spy has been extremely useful to me during this project.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I am still struggling with determining the current item. Could you take a look at this explanation here and perhaps point me in the right direction? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787902/outlook-add-in-selecting-the-active-inspector-on-item-send

Comment: See my reply for that question.